# Is this a dialog box,which folks at stackoverflow can not create?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm asking this question second time and I don't have any better option than this.
I just want to let it appear that dialog box over any apps screen. I can create dialog box like this.Means Dialog box of application 1 over application 2,3,4... screens.

Please Help to create dialog box activity as in the image?? Here 
[image]

let me explain, in chrome first i have clicked the file to download, then using intents **`Android download manager`** used its editor activity to capture the URI.. and created dialog box like this.

but i want to do that, in this image the dialog box of android download manager is over chrome. so how can I create such dialog box that appears on any app/screen when its invoked by intent. when i try to do dialog box without **setContentview** my program crashes.

Comment: thanks for the help. Hope so this expanded image will help now..

Comment: It's **NOT POSSIBLE**. A dialog box can appear **ONLY INSIDE YOUR APP**. Unless it's a **widget** app.